# Angular kendo grid performance issue?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have problem with kendo ui angular directive for grid, because I have requirement to show grid with 500-1000 items without paging and when I populate grid with more than 100 items everything become very very (VERY) slow. Is there any way to make it faster or to reduce number of watchers. Or if you have any alternative please put it in answer.

Comment: you need to load records lazily when user scrolls down the page

Comment: This question is too vague, you need to show an example of your grid for us to check if it haves any custom template/command/column/whatever... An example of your data would be good too.

Answer (score 1):

A bit hard to debug without any code examples.

If you are not allowed to use paging, perhaps you should look into [Virtualization of remote data](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/virtualization-remote-data):

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        pageSize: 100,
        transport: {
            read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
        }
    },
    height: 543,
    scrollable: {
        virtual: true
    },
    sortable: true,
    columns: [
        { field: "OrderID", title: "Order ID", width: 110 },
        { field: "CustomerID", title: "Customer ID", width: 130},
        { field: "ShipName", title:"Ship Name", width: 220 },
        { field: "ShipAddress", title:"Ship Address" },
        { field: "ShipCity", title:"Ship City", width: 130 },
        { field: "ShipCountry", title:"Ship Country", width: 130 }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed a serious slowdown with number of elements when i use k-rebind="gridOptions" and assign a datasource object to the grid options (in contrast to using a datasource configuration object). It seems like ends up deep-watching the dataSource with all its rows and fields.